# How to return today's date to a variable in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do this:

```
DECLARE @today as smalldatetime
SELECT @today = GetDate()
```

But i need an oracle translation

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Oracle uses `SYSDATE`, and there's the ANSI standard `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (supported by both SQL Server and Oracle, besides others) to get the current date & time.

```
v_today DATE;

SELECT SYSDATE
  INTO v_today
  FROM DUAL;
```

...would be the equivalent to the TSQL you posted.  Oracle uses the `INTO` clause for populating variables, where the variable data type must match the column position in the SELECT clause.

Comment: I hate the idea of using something labeled "timestamp" to return a date datatype.

Comment: you should be aware that SYSDATE is not strictly equal to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, the last converts the time to the client local zone.

Answer (score 6):

While not a strict translation, I prefer the following construction in Oracle:

```
v_today date; -- needs to go where variables are declared

v_today := sysdate; -- used where code is run.
```

Or even:

```
v_today date := sysdate;
```