# How to set current date to alias in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL Server we can declare a variable and set the date to that variable in query like this:

```
GETDATE() AS currentDate
```

How is this accomplished in Oracle?

Comment: Your title doesn't reflect the code in your question as Lukasz has explained below. Which is it... an alias or a variable that you need? Because both have been answered on Stackoverflow. [Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925144/how-to-return-todays-date-to-a-variable-in-oracle)and [Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451195/is-the-as-keyword-required-in-oracle-to-define-an-alias)

Comment: In SQLServer the GETDATE and GETUTCDATE function return the current server time with millisecond precision. 

To get the same in oracle you'll need to use the SYSTIMESTAMP function. Example:    `SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL` . If seconds precision is all you need you can use SYSDATE
.


DATETIME returned from sysdate is slightly easier to work with than a TIMESTAMP but primarily your choice should be driven by the precision required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GETDATE() AS currentDate` is a column alias:

```
SELECT SYSDATE AS currentDate FROM dual
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f88d076891863d8be670d4b16cc638e)

---

Variable declaration inside anonymous block:

```
DECLARE 
   currentDate DATE;
BEGIN
   currentDate := SYSDATE;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a2bf65c62c72beaa08ee563e4cfb1427)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INTO` in a query in PL/SQL block and in your case, even you can assign it directly in PL/SQL block.

```
Declare
lv_date1 date;
lv_date2 date;
begin
select sysdate into lv_date1 from dual; --method 1
lv_date2 := sysdate; -- method 2
end;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Using `select ... into ... from dual;` is just useless typing.

Comment: Yes, But this is to provide all the methods to OP for assigning value to a variable

Comment: Yes, that will happen but currently, my aim is to provide all the methods available for doing the task to OP.

Comment: This was necessary Back In The Day (and before my time, which is going some :-) but is pointlessly obfuscatory today. [See my question regarding this issue and its answers for further information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418779/using-select-to-call-a-function).

Comment: Thanks @BobJarvis, Learned the thing from your question.